# C# help on realtime configuration of interval using quartz

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need to make the interval dependent on the database configuration.

so for example the console application runs with 10 second interval, if i change the interval for 20 seconds its going to follow the new interval without closing the console application.

Here's the current configuration:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "1";

ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();

sched.Start();
// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Run>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1") // name "myJob", group "group1"
    .Build();


// Trigger the job to run now, and then every 30 seconds
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(f => f.WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                              .RepeatForever())
    .WithPriority(1)
    .Build();


// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Quartz.NET manual](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger), you can always change an existing trigger by re-scheduling a new one:

```
// retrieve the trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");

// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
// (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any desired way)
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
    .withRepeatCount(10)
    .build();

sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```

Comment: Nice way to not have to redefine everything except the small change.

Comment: i'm not sure if that's gonna work because when i use the debugger it does not go back to the quartz configuration after the first job ends. i want it to be dependent on the database,, whatever time i would set it must follow.

Comment: That's some different kind of logic - Quartz simply doesn't know when your configuration changes. I guess you could schedule a job that reads the database and applies changes to the scheduler configuration.